# How to make jQuery load() work in Chrome.It works in IE 10

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on Test Automation report and I am trying a load a local html in another local html file and using jQuery load for this. This is workinf fine in IE10 but not in Chrome. I want this is to work in chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title> QA Automation - Test Result Log</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/result.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready((function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("TestSummary.html");
}));
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="includedContent"></div>
<div id="main">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you directly try to open a file in Chrome, i.e `file:///` it won't work and you'll see something like:

`Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

You need to setup a web-server like `WAMP`, and then run it from localhost instead.

Comment: Thanks Michelle. But this is a test Automation report which i need to send it across team members who will need to access this offline as well. So I need to make this work offline.

Comment: @user2048204 you can try to use local network IP for accessing from other machines in the same network.